# Short circuit of voltage regulator

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb, voltage-regulator, photodiode

I am trying to design a circuit to get an amplified signal out of an OPT101 photodiode.

The photodiode contains an amplifier (and there is an additional opamp for further signal amplification on the board) that can be supplied with +/-15V, so I used an ITA0515S voltage regulator (VR1 in the schematic) to get these voltages from a +5V supply.

When I fully assemble the circuit, the voltages on the output rails of the voltage regulator drops to -2 and ~0 V. I am unsure if it is just shoddy workmanship on my side or if I built in some kind of short somewhere which creates this. Can somebody look over the schematic and tell me where I messed up?

Sorry that it is not all standard symbols - using a student Altium Designer license with the parts importer to get the footprints and that often only puts up boxes with pins on the schematic.

[image: opt101 circuit]

Comment: What is the input voltage to the regulator when the output voltage drops?

Comment: Should -Vin and Common be connected?

Comment: @MiNiMe As I use no neg. input voltage, I saw no reason not to?

Answer (score 0):

The two sources of MFT1 MOSFET are connected to nothing, except to each other. You can't expect to have any current out of the drain D2 which is supposed to feed +VIN on VR1.

Comment: Hey,
this configuration was actually taken from the datasheet of the protection IC [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX4864L-MAX4867.pdf) as back-to-back n-channel config for voltage protection. But as you are asking I feel like I missed some basic mosfet concept - can you compare with the DS (page 8, fig. 6) and tell me if I misunderstood it? I used a slightly different current mosfet (FDC8602 from onsemi), but same pin layout, because original was not avail.

Comment: @Sacharon When G1 and G2 of MFT1 are high, the current can flow in both directions. When they are low the current can't flow in neither direction. The current has to pass through the body diode. It also passes through the body diode of the P-MOSFET. Check if these body diodes can support the required current. If not add external diodes.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so there should be no issue, total current of the whole circuit after is probably in the 100mA range (roughly guessed)... However I am still unsure if there is any issue with anything BEHIND the VR1. Do you see anything?

Comment: I think that COMMON should be completely disconnected from GND, and be used as ground reference for all the circuitry powered by the VR1 output. Also bear in mind that max output current is limited to 30mA. If the circuit uses more than that it will affect voltage. https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_ITA.pdf